# qmake variable reference in project file

Tags: qt, build, qmake

I am trying to use qmake to include all files in a directory (this project is an external subversion project with hundreds of files). I am using `qmake version 3.1`.

What I tried was something like:

```
server_files = $$files($$PWD/server)
SOURCES += server_files(*.cpp, true)
```

The first line does not give any error but the second line gives:

```
:-1: warning: Failure to find: server_files(*.cpp,
:-1: warning: Failure to find: true)
```

Putting a `$` sign in front of the variable as `SOURCES += $server_files(*.cpp, true)` gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

### The following example function takes a variable name as its only argument, extracts a list of values from the variable with the eval() built-in function, and compiles a list of files:

```
defineReplace(headersAndSources) {
    variable = $$1
    names = $$eval($$variable)
    headers =
    sources =

    for(name, names) {
        header = $${name}.h
        exists($$header) {
            headers += $$header
        }
        source = $${name}.cpp
        exists($$source) {
            sources += $$source
        }
    }
    return($$headers $$sources)
}
```

[Variable Processing Functions](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-advanced-usage.html)